# OnDragEnd don't go back to starting position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using the `draggable='true'` attribute to make a draggable element in my website, but I've run into a cosmetic issue.

The dragging is basically done to reorder elements, so I want to pick them up, drag them into their new position, and then simply release them into the new position, but as soon as I let go, the element will slide back to it's original position before moving to the new position.

See this image:

[image]

How can I keep this from happening? I want to skip the "goes back" part.

```
$("div").on('dragend', function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("div.slide.placeholder").replaceWith($(this));
    updateSlides();
    
})
```

---

### Edit:

This issue has been confirmed as localized to Mac. It is very similar to the whole window-bounce effect.

Answer (score 1):

I tried coding what you want using jquery.

-->[http://jsfiddle.net/oLc2f3kp](http://jsfiddle.net/oLc2f3kp/1/)

the element that has class `.drag_item` can be draged. if you release it anywhere that isn't on the area of element that has class `.release_area`, it will go back to the position before.

I hope it's what you want. if you have any question about this code,ask me then :D

**UPDATED** I tried over many times now I have the solution

```
    $('div[class=dragable]').on('dragend',function(e){
        $(this).css('top',e.originalEvent.pageY-($(this).height()/2));
        $(this).css('left',e.originalEvent.pageX-($(this).width()/2));
    });
```

I can't get the position while I'm draging it (the position I got is the original position of the element before start dragging")
 so the only way( so far I have tested now) is to get the position of your mouse when you drop it and
 set `left` and `top` are same as the position of your mouse.

I have only tested in Chrome. anyways I don't suggest you to do this.

Comment: `ondragstart`, `ondragend`, `ondragenter`, `ondragleave`, etc are all Javascript events under the Drag events listed [on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: @David oh I've never seen it. Thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue by **not using draggable nor drag events** at all.

Instead simply use '**onmousedown**', '**onmousemove**' and '**onmouseup**' events.
A simple approach to drag any fixed item:

```
// link this to your element's left/top using your framework, jquery or plain js
const position = { x: 0, y: 0 };

const offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let dragging;

// call this in onmousedown
const onDragStart = event => {
  dragging = true;
  offset.x = event.clientX - position.value.x;
  offset.y = event.clientY - position.value.y;
}

// call this in onmousemove
const onDrag = event => {
  if (dragging) {
    position.value = {
      x: event.clientX - offset.x,
      y: event.clientY - offset.y
    };
  }
}

// call this in onmouseup
const onDragEnd = event => {
  dragging = false;
}
```

This approach also removes the annoying shadow image